# Display a Custom Validity Message for an email?

Tags: javascript

I need to display a custom validity message for an email input.

HTML:

```
<label for="email">E-mail:</label>
<input type="email" id"email" name="parentEmail">
```

What I have in JS:

```
const parentEmail = document.querySelector("#email");

function customEmailValidityMsg(){
     if(parentEmail.validity.patternMismatch){
          parentEmail.setCustomValidity("Please format the email to                              include an '@'")
     }else{
          //do nothing
     }
}

submitButton.addEventListner('click',customEmailValidityMsg);
```

Comment: id"email" is a typo. "email" is not a selector. It should be "#email" to select id. Let's see if your code will work after those fix.

Comment: changing it to "#email" didn't work